# Outlining areas of a map using rectangles

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have created a map of Newfoundland, Canada and wish to highlight Trinity Bay. I was trying to do this using `geom_rect`. It is working for me (red rectangle), although I would like to rotate the rectangle so that it contains just the bay, and none of the surrounding land (like the orange rectangle).
[image]
Here is my code:

```
library(ggplot2)
Provinces <- getData("GADM", country="CAN", level=1)

d <- ggplot() +
  geom_polygon(data=Provinces, aes(long, lat, group=group), colour="grey10", 
           fill="cadetblue1", alpha=0.8) +
  coord_map(xlim=c(-60, -52), ylim=c(46, 52)) +
  theme_bw()+
  geom_rect(aes(xmin=-53, xmax=-53.75, ymin= 47.5, ymax=48.5), alpha=0, 
        colour="red", size=1, linetype=1)
d
```

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `geom_polygon()` instead of `_rect()`.  Define the parameters and pass in.  It requires playing around with the parameters, but is easy to do - My machine is playing up, and it's taking too long to get it over the bay as you want.

```
poly <- tibble(x = c(-53.75, -53, -52, -52.75), y = c(47.5, 47.5, 48.5, 48.5))

d <- ggplot() +
  geom_polygon(data=Provinces, aes(long, lat, group=group), colour="grey10", fill="cadetblue1", alpha=0.8) +
  coord_map(xlim=c(-60, -52), ylim=c(46, 52)) +
  theme_bw()+
  geom_polygon(data = poly, aes(x = x, y = y), alpha=0, colour="red", size=1, linetype=1)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Not an expert here but could you perhaps use the arguments `hjust` and `vjust` within `geom_rect`?

Comment: I don't think you can use hjust and vjust within geom_rect as arguments!

Comment: Please comment if you are not sure of the answer. Do not post answers if you are not 100% sure.